# Disable root login in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, root

recently, when I open my Mac terminal, it runs as root default and requires a password to continue.
After I enter the password, it switches to my common account, it is so strange. I want to log in as my common account by default, not the root, any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried to change your account settings at SystemSettings/Accounts/ Login options ?